# ¿Como forzar el foco en el GridView?

Tags: java, android

¿Como forzar el foco en el GridView?

Un VideoView está haciendo que pierda el foco del GridView y por ello que no funcione OnItemClickListener.

Estuve buscando al respecto y vi que se podía forzar quitar el foco desde el XML, no he logrado que funcione. Tampoco el típico "requestFocus()".

Seguramente sea o bien por falta de conocimientos y no saber exactamente como hacer que el GirdView mantenga el foco, por ello me gustaría saber como puedo tener el foco en el GridView (este GridView contiene una serie de VideoView con un título) y puedan ser pulsados a través del OnItemClicListener.

**Edito**: Si pongo el VideoView con el atributo android:visibility="invisible" funciona todo correctamente, por eso me da a pensar que es culpa del VideoView el tema del foco.

Layout que contiene VideoView y TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gvEjemplosAdaptador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vvEjemplosAdaptador"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="102dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEjemplosNombresVideos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout que contiene el GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".video.reproductor_video_ejemplo">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/imagen_fondo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoViewMuestra"
            style="@style/videoView_portrait" />



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridViewEjemplos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/datos_autor"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adaptador para luego pasarselo al GridView:

```
public class adaptador_videos_ejemplo extends BaseAdapter {

private Context contexto;
private int layout;
private ArrayList<video> misVideos;

    public adaptador_videos_ejemplo(Context c, int layout, ArrayList<video> listaVideos){
        this.contexto = c;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.misVideos = listaVideos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.misVideos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.misVideos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int posicion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //cargo la lista
        View v = convertView;

        //inflo la vista que nos llega con el layout personalizado
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this.contexto);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.adaptador_videos_ejemplos,null);

        //extraigo los datos (esto es por cada iteración)
        String nombreActual = misVideos.get(posicion).getNombre();
        int idVideo = misVideos.get(posicion).getPath();

        //Path del mp4 como recurso
        // Cargar Video principal Path del mp4 como recurso
        String pathVideoFileMuestra = "android.resource://com.foc.reproductorvideo/" + idVideo;

        //Busco los textView que hay en mi layout personalizado
        TextView tvEjemplosNombresVideos = v.findViewById(R.id.tvEjemplosNombresVideos);
        VideoView vvEjemplosAdaptador = v.findViewById(R.id.vvEjemplosAdaptador);

        //asigno los datos a los diferentes TextView
        tvEjemplosNombresVideos.setText(nombreActual);

        //VideoView
        vvEjemplosAdaptador.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(pathVideoFileMuestra));
        vvEjemplosAdaptador.start();

        //devuelvo la vista
        return v;
    }
}
```

Clase que establece algunos recursos a modo de prueba, crea el adaptador y lo enlaza con el GridView, posteriormente se llama al método setOnItemClickListener en ver de implementarlo ya que es solo a modo de prueba. Nota: tiene un condicional para que solo funcione en modo PORTRAIT.

```
public class reproductor_video_ejemplo extends AppCompatActivity {


    VideoView vvMuestra = null;
    GridView gvEjemplos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reproductor_video_ejemplo);

        //El GridView solo se cargará en modo protrait
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

            gvEjemplos = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewEjemplos);

            ArrayList<video> misVideos = new ArrayList<>();

            misVideos.add(new video("video1", R.raw.video1));
            misVideos.add(new video("video2", R.raw.video2));
            misVideos.add(new video("video3", R.raw.video3));
            misVideos.add(new video("video4", R.raw.video4));

            //Llamo a mi adaptador
            adaptador_videos_ejemplo ave = new adaptador_videos_ejemplo(this, R.layout.adaptador_videos_ejemplos, misVideos);
            gvEjemplos.setAdapter(ave);

            //Todo - No funciona ¿No tiene el foco? 
            gvEjemplos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //Toast para saber si se pulsó.
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Se ha pulsado" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            // Cargar Video principal Path del mp4 como recurso
            String pathVideoFileMuestra = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video1;

            vvMuestra = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewMuestra);

            vvMuestra.setMediaController(new MediaController(vvMuestra.getContext()));

            vvMuestra.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(pathVideoFileMuestra));

            vvMuestra.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues nada, después de horas y al final acudir a vosotros dí con la solución probando de editar el adaptador.

Era tan simple como hacer que cada VideoView perdiera el foco de manera independiente en el adaptador a través del método setFocusable(false).

Espero que a alguien le sirva.

El método de mi adaptador quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int posicion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //cargo la lista
        View v = convertView;

        //inflo la vista que nos llega con el layout personalizado
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this.contexto);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.adaptador_videos_ejemplos,null);

        //extraigo los datos (esto es por cada iteración)
        String nombreActual = misVideos.get(posicion).getNombre();
        int idVideo = misVideos.get(posicion).getPath();

        //Path del mp4 como recurso
        // Cargar Video principal Path del mp4 como recurso
        String pathVideoFileMuestra = "android.resource://com.foc.reproductorvideo/" + idVideo;

        //Busco los textView que hay en mi layout personalizado
        TextView tvEjemplosNombresVideos = v.findViewById(R.id.tvEjemplosNombresVideos);
        VideoView vvEjemplosAdaptador = v.findViewById(R.id.vvEjemplosAdaptador);

        //asigno los datos a los diferentes TextView
        tvEjemplosNombresVideos.setText(nombreActual);

        //VideoView
        vvEjemplosAdaptador.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(pathVideoFileMuestra));
        vvEjemplosAdaptador.start();

        //vvEjemplosAdaptador.clearFocus();
        vvEjemplosAdaptador.setFocusable(false);

        //devuelvo la vista
        return v;
    }
```